# How do I highlight a role on an embed message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do I highlight a role or any role in an embedded message?

I've tried this:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'role test') {
  let = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ADMIN");
  let uEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`pong ${role}`);
  message.channel.send({embed: uEmbed})

};
```

It gave me this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: role is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `let = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ADMIN");`

See the mistake? What variable would contain that info?

Comment: I don’t really know im new to this, i asked someone and they told me to put that but didnt work.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. You are declaring a variable without giving a name to it. `let = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ADMIN");` should be `let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ADMIN");`. `role` is now the name of the variable that stores the information of the role named "ADMIN". The code itself should sound English enough (kind of like Maths letting a variable to equal to an equation like `let y = f(x)`) that reads: let variable "role" be equal to the information of role named "ADMIN". Hope this makes sense.